# How to show capital letters when shift key is pressed using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on a project which needs to show keyboard on a popup with small letters and capital letters. I'm done with small letters but when I press shift key all the letters should turn into capital letters. In this example I need to show the letters z,x,c,v,b as capitals when I click on Shift button. How can I acheive this? Thanks in advance. This is the code I have written so far:

```js
 $scope.isShift = false;
        $scope.shiftPress = function() {
            $scope.isShift = !$scope.isShift;
        };
        $scope.printKey = function(value) {
            return $scope.isShift ? $filter('uppercase')(value) : value;
        };
}

$scope.numberclick = function(value){
        $scope.printKey(value);
}
```

```html
<button class="Val-bt" ng-click="shiftPress()">Shift</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('z')">{{ printKey('z') }}</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('x')">{{ printKey('x') }}</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('c')">{{ printKey('c') }}</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('v')">{{ printKey('v') }}</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('b')">{{ printKey('b') }}</button>
```

Comment: It may be simpler to add a class to the parent `div` of the `keyboard` buttons and have css that does the text-transform on child buttons. `div.with-shift button { text-transform: "capitalize"; }`

Comment: can't you make it work with **value.toUpperCase()";

Comment: @ManishSingh No, it's not working with toUppserCase() method.

Answer (score 4):

You have to run a loop because `document.getElementsByClassName('Val-bt')` returns an array and you can set css to its element directly.

```js
function shiftPress() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('Val-bt');

  var i=0;
  var is = buttons[i].style.textTransform;
  if(is == "capitalize"){
    for(i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
      buttons[i].style.textTransform = "lowercase";
    }
  }
  else{
    for(i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
      buttons[i].style.textTransform = "capitalize";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="Val-bt" onclick="shiftPress()">Shift</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('z')">z</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('x')">x</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('c')">c</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('v')">v</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('b')">b</button>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to capitalize the `innetHTML`/`innerText` then use this:

```js
function shiftPress() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('Val-bt');

  var i=buttons.length-1;
  var is = buttons[i].innerHTML.charAt(0);
  console.log(is);
  var isn = is.toUpperCase()
  if(is == isn){
    for(i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
      var buttonhtml = buttons[i].innerHTML;
      buttonhtml = buttonhtml.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+buttonhtml.slice(1);
      buttons[i].innerHTML = buttonhtml;
    }
  }
  else{
    for(i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
      var buttonhtml = buttons[i].innerHTML;
      buttonhtml = buttonhtml.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+buttonhtml.slice(1);
      buttons[i].innerHTML = buttonhtml;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="Val-bt" onclick="shiftPress()">Shift</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('z')">z</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('x')">x</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('c')">c</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('v')">v</button>
 <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('b')">b</button>
```

Comment: sorry, I am not that familiar with angular.

Comment: @kittyCat This works greatly,thanks. But if I press the shift button again, letters should turn into small letters. How this can be done?

Comment: @User  I have updated my answer. you can take a look.

Comment: @User  Also I have used `capitalize` here. which sets fist letter of the word to capital. If you were looking to set allthe letters to uppercase then you have to use `uppercase` instead of `capitalize`

Comment: @kittyCat This works gratly, thanks. But here I have another problem, while displaying the value, when I press the captial letter button the value is passing like small letter only but it should pass like captial and display capital letter.

Comment: @User that is because we are setting the css here. The html is still small letters, but the css is making it look like it is capital. I can try another snippet to  change the html. I will update the answer.

Comment: @User I have added another snippet in my answer that  capitalizes innerHTML. you can use innerText too, instead of innerHTML.

Comment: @kittyCat It's not working. Even the previous functionality was gone. Unable to change the letters to capital when press the shift button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133890/discussion-between-user-and-kittycat).

Answer (score 3):

Let's avoid manipulating the DOM directly and use a bit more Angular instead.. We can toggle an `isShift` state in the controller that will denote whether the keys are upper/lower case.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ce0182of/)

Controller:

```
$scope.isShift = false;

$scope.shiftPress = function() {
    $scope.isShift = !$scope.isShift;
};

$scope.printKey = function(input) {
    return $scope.isShift ? $filter('uppercase')(input) : input;
};

$scope.numberclick = function (input)
{
    input = $scope.printKey(input);

    console.log(input); // to check

    // do whatever with input
}
```

View:

```
<button class="Val-bt" ng-click="shiftPress()">Shift</button>
<button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('z')">{{ printKey('z') }}</button>
<button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('x')">{{ printKey('x') }}</button>
<button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('c')">{{ printKey('c') }}</button>
<button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('v')">{{ printKey('v') }}</button>
<button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('b')">{{ printKey('b') }}</button>
```

Comment: I think using js only to toggle a class is probably less expensive than using a filter. But this is much much better than the original solution!

Comment: @BenTaliadoros I don't disagree with you, although this solution also has the benefit of being way more testable.

Comment: @Ankh This works gratly, thanks. But here I have another problem that, while displaying the value, when I press the captial letter button the value is passing like small letter only but it should pass like captial and display capital letter.

Comment: In your `numberclick` function just make a call to `printKey` and pass the input in. It'll return the letter in the correct format.

Comment: @Ankh Its not working friend. I updated my code with numberclick() function. pls check the code.

Comment: @User what is `numberclick` supposed to do? In my edited answer I've shown you how to get the correct input value. What you do with it then I don't know as you haven't said...

Comment: @Ankh I used this code in numberclick() function var input = $scope.isShift ? $filter('uppercase')(value) : value; and passed the input value to display the clicked value. Now it is working fine. Thank you so much for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive on a parent element that attaches an event listener to the shift key.

You can alternatively pass in a scope variable with two way binding which you update.

This will run code whenever you hit the shift key. There are many examples of this.

What you want to do is change a scope variable, something like

```
$scope.keyPress = {shift: true/false};
```

That keypress variable should be on the template with an ng-class, for example:

```
<button ng-class="{capitalise: keyPress.shift}" class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('c')"></button>
```

then in your css:

```
button.Val-bt.capitalise {
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

EDIT

Seeing you want to change it on button press, just do

```
<button class="Val-bt" ng-click="keyPress.capitalise = !!!keyPress.capitalise">Shift</button>
```

make sure $scope.keypress is already defined. Everything above apart form the directive bit still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, with toggle:

```js
function shiftPress() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('with-shift');
}
```

```css
body.with-shift div.keyboard > button {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyboard">
  <button class="Val-bt" onclick="shiftPress()">Shift</button>
  <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('z')">z</button>
  <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('x')">x</button>
  <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('c')">c</button>
  <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('v')">v</button>
  <button class="Val-bt" ng-click="numberclick('b')">b</button>
</div>
```